# Where Does Envelope Come From In Fourier Transform Spectrometers?

Tags: experimental-physics, interferometry

[image]

Here I a Michelson interferometer setup, with an interferogram output of a monochromatic light source (laser). As the translation stage moves, the interferogram amplitude is modulated with another envelope. I am doing a lab course, where I took this measurement with a helium-neon laser. However, I am unable to rationalize why the envelope exists and where it is coming from. If it is truly monochromatic, then it should not exist. Could someone please help me understand this affect?

Comment: See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/510132/multiple-wavelength-peaks-in-hene-spectrum-from-ftir

Comment: Take a quick look at my computer simulated FT spectrometer here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/60031/41790. If you just have a monochromatic source, then the interferogram is contains only one frequency, which is proportional to the light’s wavenumber. Then the processing gives you back a constant.